# Where are the thugs who reveal the Riddler trophy locations?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In *Batman: Arkham City*, you had to interrogate a thug and he would give you the Riddler trophy locations, but I'm playing in hard mode and I cant find any thugs to interrogate... so how can I find all the trophies?

Comment: Just keep looking. They are there.

Comment: I'm pretty certain your Riddler Trophy progress carries over to New Game+, so it's possible you've got them already.

Answer (score 8):

Hard mode or not, all "Riddler Henchmen" glow green in Detective mode.